# Capture Image Crash Source type 1 not available even though checking if camera is available

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I received a crash report from an iPhone 5s running iOS 10.2.1 with the device face up.

I am checking if the camera is available with:

```
if (UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil) || (UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Front) != nil) {
    shootPhoto()    
}
```

The backtrace implies the crash occurs in shootPhoto() on the picker.sourceType line:

```
func shootPhoto() { 
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
    picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
    picker.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Since I am first checking that the camera is available, I don't understand why it is crashing. Do I need to check `UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.Camera)`? I can't reproduce the issue, so I am not sure if that would resolve it, would it? Or is there something else I need to check?

The backtrace:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
Source type 1 not available
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1913f51b8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18fe2c55c objc_exception_throw
2  UIKit                          0x197505714 +[UIImagePickerController _isMediaTypeAvailable:forSource:]
3  MyApp                         0x1000afd8c TDTStartingViewViewController.(buttonActon(UIButton) -> ()).(closure #2) (TDTStartingViewViewController.swift:887)
4  UIKit                          0x19774512c -[UIAlertController _invokeHandlersForAction:]
5  UIKit                          0x1977459c8 __85-[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:]_block_invoke.443
6  UIKit                          0x1975f6130 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:]
7  UIKit                          0x1975f98b0 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2
8  UIKit                          0x1973d1be8 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:]
9  UIKit                          0x1972e35b8 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:]
10 UIKit                          0x1972e30dc -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
11 UIKit                          0x1972e2ef8 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
12 QuartzCore                     0x1947517e8 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*)
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x19027e1bc _dispatch_client_callout
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x190282d68 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1913a2810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1913a03fc __CFRunLoopRun
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1912ce2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
18 GraphicsServices               0x192d82198 GSEventRunModal
19 UIKit                          0x1973157fc -[UIApplication _run]
20 UIKit                          0x197310534 UIApplicationMain
21 MyApp                         0x1001329ec main (AppDelegate.swift:24)
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x1902b15b8 (Missing)
```

EDIT: Proposed Code (checks for available media types and capture modes), this seems to work, thoughts/suggestions?

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {  //returns YES if source is available (i.e. camera present)

    if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.Rear) || UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.Front) { //returns YES if camera device is available

        var isImageMediaTypeAvailble = false
        var rearCameraSupportsPhotoCapture = false
        var frontCameraSupportsPhotoCapture = false
        let availableMediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.Camera) //returns array of available media types (i.e. kUTTypeImage)

        if availableMediaTypes != nil {
            for mediaType in availableMediaTypes! {
                if mediaType == kUTTypeImage as String {
                    isImageMediaTypeAvailble = true
                }
            }
        }

        if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.Rear) {
            let availableCaptureModes = UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) // returns array of NSNumbers (UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode)
            if availableCaptureModes != nil {
                for mode in availableCaptureModes! {
                    if mode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Photo.rawValue { //camera can capture image
                        rearCameraSupportsPhotoCapture = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.Front) {
            let availableCaptureModes = UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Front) // returns array of NSNumbers (UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode)
            if availableCaptureModes != nil {
                for mode in availableCaptureModes! {
                    if mode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Photo.rawValue { //camera can capture image
                        frontCameraSupportsPhotoCapture = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) && isImageMediaTypeAvailble && (rearCameraSupportsPhotoCapture || frontCameraSupportsPhotoCapture) {
            actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in
                self.shootPhoto()
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say that? `availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice` expects a value from `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice` and both `.Rear` and `.Front` are valid members.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition,

```
open class func availableCaptureModes(for cameraDevice: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice) -> [NSNumber]? 
// returns array of NSNumbers (UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode)
```

`availableCaptureModes` returns array of `UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode`

```
public enum UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode : Int {
    case photo
    case video
}
```

I guess you need to check `.photo` is available mode before you set

```
picker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
```

Also it looks like you need to check `availableMediaTypes` with

```
open class func availableMediaTypes(for sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) -> [String]? 
// returns array of available media types (i.e. kUTTypeImage)
```

I think that is what you log says

```
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18fe2c55c objc_exception_throw
2  UIKit                          0x197505714 +[UIImagePickerController _isMediaTypeAvailable:forSource:]
```

Comment: What class is the `availableCaptureModes` part of? I don't see it, but I do see `UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice)`

Comment: I think you are using `swift 2.x`. There might be a method/enum/property with similar name to `swift 3.x`'s. It is `UIImagePickerController`'s class method.

Comment: Yeah, still on Swift 2.3, so I guess use `availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice‌` instead?

Comment: I guess `[UIImagePickerController _isMediaTypeAvailable:forSource:]` this is what you need to use. The log tells you it crashed there. There must be a equivalent method to `availableMediaTypes()` in swift 2.x. like `isMediaTypeAvailable:forSource`

Comment: Cool, yeah, in my question I even asked if I need to use `UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.Camera)`

Comment: Actually, looks like I need to check: `UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)` as that is the type being set on the offending line.

Comment: Please see my edit for proposed new code (sorry I didn't save the page before). Sure is a lot more checking than all the capture image examples I have seen but seems to work.